# Home page get blank when spfx webpart added

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I have one custom SPFx webpart which fetches the event from calendar. the webpart is working fine but when I place the webpart on home page communication site. the home page shows blank.

If i add the webpart on other site pages then those pages working fine. only home page is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see if there is an error in the page when you add this web part.

In addition, try a different browser to see if you have the same problem.

If the problem persists, for this question, I recommend your [create service requests to contact Office 365 support.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenkumar/2013/07/17/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support/)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. I've put some more analysis and details in [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167517/spfx-provisioning-a-web-part-by-code-on-a-home-page-removes-other-contents) question, and submitted a [SharePoint UserVoice entry](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/38711152-enable-to-add-web-parts-programmatically-to-newly) to get a solution from the SP dev team. Please vote for it !